Organizing DataFrames from several spreadsheets
I have several spreadsheets with tax data for each month. I organized them into folders labeled after each year (2009, 2010, etc.). Each folder contains 12 spreadsheets for each month.
There are two problems:

Inconsistency. Spreadsheets may be organized differently.

Example: Picture 1
Picture 2
What is the best way to import spreadsheets without including unnecessary text (highlighted in red)?

What is the best approach to combine spreadsheets into a single dataframe that contains tax data for the whole year.

I tried using glob to import spreadsheets and append them to a single DF.
path = r'C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\Data\2009'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xls"))

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None, sheet_name='РК')
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True) 

However, what I get is the first spreadsheet being imported somewhat properly and other sheets being imported with nothing but NaN values.
Result

Without having the data to test with this is very difficult to answer. And the cyrillic script doesnt help.

Does this answer your question? Pandas - First find header, then only load certain columns on an Excel sheet. This should help you dynamically locate page header, read tables as dataframes and merge them.

you could just read each spreadsheet seperately and then concat the dataframes together
